# App Store iPad Requirements: How to add iPad mini?

Tags: ipad, app-store

How do you ensure that iPad Mini is included in the App Store requirements list? I have a universal app and it just doesn't seem to be included...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest that you read the list you posted once again.

Comment: Why? Both apps are universal, but only one supports iPad mini.